# Reverse DNS does not contain the hostname and RDNS_NONE from spam assasing

Tags: linux, email, reverse-dns, cloudflare, plesk

So i am trying to setup the reverse dns for my server and i got it mapping correctly to my mail domain and i did a test on mail-test but reverse dns failed with: `Spam Assasin RDNS_NONE`, but on mail authentication bellow shows is correctly authenticated with rDns: `IP: xx.xxx.xxx.xx HELO: mail.xxxxxx.com rDNS: mail.xxxxxx.com` and also i did a test on MxToolBox for email health and i get this warning: `Reverse DNS does not contain the hostname`, i checked my reverse lookup with dig -x xx.xxx.xxx.xx and the result was this, i get 2 dns results on **ANSWER SECTION** but one is only mail. and the other is the full one mail.xxxxxx.com, how to fix this? it have something to do with my issue?:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.13-Ubuntu <<>> -x xx.xxx.xxx.xx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9297
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xx.xxx.xxx.xx.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
xx.xxx.xxx.xx.in-addr.arpa. 0   IN      PTR     mail.xxxxx.com.
xx.xxx.xxx.xx.in-addr.arpa. 0   IN      PTR     mail. //Why both? and why this only is only the subdomain wihtout the full one?

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sat Dec 05 20:08:59 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 101
```

Comment: Remove the incorrect one.

Comment: @MichaelHampton how i can do that? on my server provider there is only the mail.xxxxx.com on reverse dns and i also only have setup 1 ptr record to mail.xxxxxx.com

Comment: If you only set one record but two are in the DNS, you should be having a chat with the provider.

Comment: Also notice that `mail.` is not "only the subdomain", but it refers to a TLD that doesn't exist, as ICANN has decided in [Resolution 2018.02.04.12](https://www.icann.org/resources/board-material/resolutions-2018-02-04-en#2.c):  "However, the New gTLD Program has brought renewed attention to this issue of queries for undelegated TLDs at the root level of the DNS because certain applied-for new TLD strings could be identical to name labels used in private networks (i.e., .HOME, .CORP, and .MAIL). A secure, stable, and resilient Internet is ICANN's number one priority."

Comment: So what i should do to fix this? It can be fixed by my own or i should contact my dns provider? thank to both.